# JIRA JQL Query to find issues statusCategoryChangedDate after the due date

Tags: jira, jql

I am writing a jql query to find issues where their status category was updated to done after the due date. I want to determine the number of issues that weren't completed by their due date.

`project in (ABC) AND statusCategory = Done AND statusCategoryChangedDate > due +1d`

I have tried doing this:

`project in (ABC) AND statusCategory = Done AND statusCategoryChangedDate > due +1d`

I am unable to use issueFunction.  I am trying to find a workaround this. Can someone please help me?